# Knockout observable array sorting not working

Tags: knockout.js

I try to sort a Knockout array with the usual methods but it's not working. I want to sort it by totalTTC value. Here is  the element in the view model:

```
appViewModel.orders = ko.computed(() -> (
  orders = []
  # Check if seller of this shoppingCartLine exists
  appViewModel.shoppingCartLines().forEach((shoppingCartLine) ->
  existingOrder = null
  orders.forEach((order) ->
    if order.seller? and order.seller.id() ==    shoppingCartLine.ad.ownerJson.id()
      existingOrder = order
  )
  # If it exits add it to its shoppingCartLines array
  if existingOrder?
    existingOrder.shoppingCartLines.push(shoppingCartLine)
    return
  # Otherwise create a new order from this shoppingCartLine
  else
    seller = shoppingCartLine.ad.ownerJson
    shoppingCartLines = ko.observableArray([shoppingCartLine])
    order = new Order(seller, shoppingCartLines, appViewModel.freeShippingFeesThreshold)
    orders.push(order)
    return
  )
  return orders
))
```

And here is my foreach in the view:

```
<td data-bind="foreach: {data: orders().sort(function (o, r) { return o.totalTTC() > r.totalTTC() ? 1 : -1 }), as: 'order'}">
```

Does someone see what's wrong ? Thanks

Comment: Is it not returning anything, or just not in the expected order?
It might be cleaner to add an additional computed property that takes the 'orders' and returns the sorted version.

Comment: @MikeB. It's returning the data but not in the expected order. You think I should create another array sorted and return this one ?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would try.  You already have `appViewModel.orders` as defined above, so I would just add `appViewModel.sortedOrders` as another computed property that takes the (already computed) orders and returns them sorted how you want... then use `sortedOrders` in your view.  If nothing else, it might at least make the sorting easier to debug if there's a problem there.